# Alter Js/css path or overwrite on request in mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a page where css/js paths are written like below

```
~/js/view/jscript.js
~/css/View/Style.css
```

Now we have moved these files in cdn.

What do we need if we are working locally it should use ~/file and if on server it should use cdn path?

Is there any method which will catch each file request so that it can be transformed

I am looking for something config based, to url rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Use [Web.config Transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations#a-setting-that-youll-handle-in-publish-profile-transformation-files) to set an `appSettings` key with the appropriate URL in each Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config, and reference that in your view code.

```html
using System.Configuration;

@{ 
    var jsPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jsPath"];
    var cssPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cssPath"];
}

<script src="@jsPath"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@cssPath">
```

**For local use Web.Debug.config**

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="jsPath" src="~/js/view/jscript.js" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="cssPath" src="~/css/View/Style.css" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>
```

**For production use Web.Release.config**

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="jsPath" src="https://cdnpath.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
    <add key="cssPath" src="https://cdnpath.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>
```

As an added benefit, you can change the `appSettings` key at any time to change the path to the resources without having to recompile or redeploy.

Comment: I have lots of css file and js in my app in multiple pages, I am looking for something url rewrite